# Where does the gray bulk on top of screen come from?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a React Native app with React Native CLI.
The `App.tsx` has the following content:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Hello React</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default App;
```

The app is very straightforward, it shows only `Hello React`.
What does disturb me is the gray bulk on the top:

[image]

and I do not know, where it comes from.

My virtual device:
[image]

React Native version 0.65.

**Could you please tell me, where the gray bulk comes from?**

The repository is hosted on https://github.com/softshipper/GrayBulk.

**Update**

I have changed the `App` component to:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from "react-native";


import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "blue" }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default App;
```

and the gray bulk still appears:
[image]

Comment: What version of `react-native-safe-area-context` are you using? You can change the color by setting `style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}` Docs: https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context#example-1

Comment: I added the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SafeAreaView and change it to View to remove the boundaries and then give the component flex: 1, then paddingTop: 25 and backgroundColor: white.

Comment: I would like to keep `SafeAreaView`.

Comment: Could you please tell me, where the gray bulk comes from?

Comment: That is the default status bar color of the device

Comment: Try adding this `<StatusBar translucent={true} hidden={true} /> ` immediately after opening the `<SafeAreaView>` tag